# Binary representation of a number

Tags: binary

Below code is for Binary Representation of a Number.
This code works fine.....but i don't know why
`if((x&(0x80000000))>0)` should be `<0` instead of `>0`
because if first bit of x is 1, the number generated would be -2147483748, which is less than 0 but still this code works.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    for(int i=0;i<32;i++) 
    {
        if((x&(0x80000000))>0)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0"); 
        x=x<<1;
    }
    printf("\n");
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `!=` instead of `>`?

Comment: != works .. but i want to know what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4):

The type of a hexadecimal constant, such as `0x80000000`, is the first of these types that its value fits in:

- int
- unsigned int
- long int
- unsigned long int
- long long int
- unsigned long long int

In a C implementation where `int` and `unsigned int` are 32 bits, `0x80000000` does not fit in an `int`. So it is an unsigned int. Then, in `x & 0x80000000`, x is promoted from `int` to `unsigned int` to match. Thus, the expression is unsigned, and the value is greater than zero, not less than zero.